# How to dynamically remove a button from Xaml in C++ Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, c++-cx

This is how I create a button dynamically in C++ (Visual Studio C++ 2017):

```
    Button^ myButton = ref new Button();
myButton->Content = "Button";
myButton->Height = 80;
myButton->Width = 150;
ContentPanel->Children->Append(myButton);
```

How am I to remove this button from the ContentPanel dynamically?

```
ContentPanel->Children-> RemoveAt(myButton);
```

does not work and generates an error. What am I doing wrong here?

COMPLETE EXAMPLE:

```
    <Page
x:Class="App3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Hello!" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="InputButton" Content="Click" Click="InputButton_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

```
// MainPage.xaml.cpp
// Implementation of the MainPage class.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"

using namespace App3;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
}


void App3::MainPage::InputButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender,     Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
Button^ myButton = ref new Button();
if (myButton != nullptr)
{

    myButton->Margin = Thickness(10);
    myButton->Content = "myButton";
    myButton->Height = 80;
    myButton->Width = 150;
    myButton->Foreground = ref new SolidColorBrush (Windows::UI::Colors::Lavender);
    myButton->Background = ref new SolidColorBrush(Windows::UI::Colors::Olive);
    ContentPanel->Children->Append(myButton);
}
else
    ContentPanel->Children->RemoveAt(myButton);
```

}

In addition, I guess that (myButton != nullptr) is not the proper way to test whether the 'myButton' was already created dynamically (in previous call of the 'InputButton_Click')

Comment: What's your error in particular? Can you provide a [MCVE] please?

Comment: It generates two errors: E1767 and C2664:
Error (active) E1767 function "Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::UIElementCollection::RemoveAt" cannot be called with the given argument list App2 c:\Users\ZM\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App2\App2\MainPage.xaml.cpp 79

Error C2664 'void Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::UIElementCollection::RemoveAt(unsigned int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button ^' to 'unsigned int' App2 c:\users\zm\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\app2\app2\mainpage.xaml.cpp 79

Comment: [edit] your question please to add additional information!

Comment: You probably _oversimplified_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RemoveAt` takes an index of item to be removed. You should save it somewhere when adding new item and use later to remove it.

```
    m_button_index = ContentPanel->Children->Size;
    ContentPanel->Children->Append(myButton);
}
else
    ContentPanel->Children->RemoveAt(m_button_index);
```

Also note that check `myButton != nullptr` is pointless because allocated button is either not null or an exception is thrown so your code will always add button.

Comment: Thank you, the removal of the myButton worked in the end. But still, how can one test whether <grid> contains certain item, i.e. myButton? (I am still working on it, therefore I did not post it yet as a question but if I'll will not be able to solve it within reasonable time, I might.)

Comment: `Children` property returns an [`U​IElement​Collection` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection) that has `IndexOf` method that looks like it does the right thing.